# How to compile and reference a project in a solution, but not be able to modify its source?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We have Component A that can accept plugins from Components B and C. We have a Visual Studio 2010 solution devoted to each Component (Solutions A, B and C). We would like Solution A to somehow cause the plugins from B and C to be compiled as needed, but we don't want developers to change the plugins' code from within Solution A. It would be perfect if the projects for plugins B and C were part of Solution A, but the source code for the plugins were not modifiable there, but we don't see how that's possible.

We have considered using a pre-build event somewhere in Solution A to build the plugins, but that doesn't work because the pre-build event would only kick off according to *its* project's dependencies, not according to the plugins' dependencies.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have a build server (CI server)? You _could_ configure most build server to do cascading builds (setting dependencies etc).

Comment: Yes, we do have a CI server. However, my interest is in what happens on developers' workstations.